# How to get properties of picked object in mplot3d (matplotlib + python)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, picker, mplot3d

I plot a series of points using `mplot3d`:

```
import pylab as p
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3

fig = p.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter([1], [0], [0], c='r', marker='^', picker=5)
ax.scatter([0], [1], [0], c='g', marker='^', picker=5)
ax.scatter([0], [0], [1], c='b', marker='^', picker=5)
```

and then I add a picker function:

```
def onpick(event):
   ind = event.ind
   print ind

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

and finally plot it:

```
p.show()
```

Is there a way of getting the 3D coordinates from the marker I am clicking?
So far I can get the index of the point in the list I used at `ax.scatter()`, but that wont cut it as I use `ax.scatter()` many times and this has to be this way (I use different colors for example).

Regards

Answer (score 10):

You can use _offsets3d attribute of event.artist to get the coordinate data, and then use ind to get the picked point:

```
def onpick(event):
    ind = event.ind[0]
    x, y, z = event.artist._offsets3d
    print x[ind], y[ind], z[ind]
```